# Is it possible to specify a directory/folder for mongodump?

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

I'd like to specify the directory to which [mongodump](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools) dumps, via a switch on the mongodump command.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You don't need a script. From [the docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#bin.mongodump):

> ### `--out <path>, -o <path>`
>
> Specifies the directory where mongodump will write BSON files for the dumped databases.

Example:

```
mongodump -o /mydir/
```

Lots of other options there, check it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can view all the commands for mongodump by typing "mongodump --help" in the command prompt (NB. You have to be in the folder that contains mongodump.exe).

You can use a command like:

```
mongodump /host <hostIP> /port <port> /d <database> /c <collection> /o <outputDirectoryPath>
```

Answer (score 1):

It Dumps my_db in a gzip format inside tmp/my_db.dump file
which is Restoreable

`mongodump --db my_db --gzip -o ./tmp/my_db.dump`

Comment: Please explain what this command do. So other people can benefit from your answer. Just a command as answer is not really meaningful.

Comment: It Dumps my_db in a gzip format inside tmp/my_db.dump file

Comment: which is Restoreable

Comment: Please add the explanation to the answer not below in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

When I am using windows I always use the command below because it exports in a folder with export date:

```
setlocal enableextensions
set FOLDER_NAME=%DATE:/=_%
mongodump --uri "mongodb+srv://USER:PASSWORD@URL/DATABASE_NAME" -o C:\work\scheduled\dump\backup-%FOLDER_NAME%
```

Save the command in a file with bat extension (dump.bat for example)